# Powershell Get-WmiObject generic-failure

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I'm struggling with a wmi query (running in Administrator Powershell) that is failing with a generic failure...

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpdevice
```

results in:

```
Get-WmiObject : Generic failure At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  -Class win32_pnpdevice
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

This happens on Windows 10 IoT, Windows 10 1809 Enterprise and Windows Embedded S7.
For Windows Server 2016 the query is working fine...

I already tried repairing wmi with

```
net stop winmgmt
winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem
winmgmt /resetrepository %windir%\System32\wbem
net start winmgmt
```

and also renamed the repository folder in C:\Windows\System32\wbem and rebuild the repository. But the query is still not working.

Calling the query via python brings some more error codes:

```
>>> import wmi
>>> w = wmi.WMI()
>>> pnp = w.Win32_PnPDevice()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Engineering\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 880, in query
    return self._namespace.query(wql, self, fields)
  File "C:\Users\Engineering\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1072, in query
    return [ _wmi_object(obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Users\Engineering\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1072, in <listcomp>
    return [ _wmi_object(obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Users\Engineering\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 236, in __getitem__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._enum_.__getitem__(index))
  File "C:\Users\Engineering\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 37, in __getitem__
    return self.__GetIndex(index)
  File "C:\Users\Engineering\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 53, in __GetIndex
    result = self._oleobj_.Next(1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147217407, 'OLE error 0x80041001', None, None)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does wmic work in cmd? See this post and follow the steps mentioning re-installing windows installer: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c679891c-ec68-4674-948d-9b7e3548aa6c/getwmiobject-generic-failure?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: For some queries it works, for some not:
PS C:\Users\Engineering> WMIC PATH Win32_PnPDevice GET /VALUE
Node - xxxx
ERROR:
Description = Generic failure

Answer (score 0):

- Windows 7 x64

I've tried almost everything here and there to fix it, but nothing works from what I've found. The `wbemtest` is returned the same text plus error `0x80041001`. Nor WMI service restart or WMI repository reset. Nor numerious MSDN forums.

Nor performance counters restore:

https://community.progress.com/s/article/WMI-Based-Active-Monitors-fail-with-error-Generic-Failure-or-Invalid-Query

> **Resolution**
>
> When you get a Generic Failure or Invalid Query, but there doesn't seem to be an issue with the query, it is often the case that there is an issue with a Performance Monitor counter, or its availability on the device you are monitoring.
>
> **To create the necessary counters**:
>
> - Open an elevated Command Prompt (Right click and select Run as Administrator)
> - For 64-bit Operating Systems, enter the following two commands; for 32-bit Operating Systems, just enter the first command below:
>
>   ```
>   %WINDIR%\system32\lodctr /R
>   %WINDIR%\SysWow64\lodctr /R
>   ```
> - Once you have done this, open Performance Monitor again, and confirm that the counters are now available

In the next I've found this:

http://www.nullskull.com/q/81326/remote-wmi--generic-failure-0x80041001.aspx

And tried to run:

```
wmic /node:'randomtext' path win32_Product get name
```

The command and output is not related to the issue, but the error in the Event Log got an accidental direction to search:

```
windows event DCOM 10009
```

And found this:

http://forum.oszone.net/post-1276605.html#post1276605

Where the registry key is mentioned:

```
HKCU\Printers\Connections\<computer name>\<Printer>`
```

Then I've tried to start the Print Spooler service and it worked out:

```
net start Spooler
```

I have no idea how is it connected to the issue.